# Add a Mapbox marker on double click event using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, marker, mapbox-gl

I'm having some difficulties making my code work. I'm working on an interactive map and I want to add a function that when users "double click" it allows them to add a marker, the function is supposed to pull the long and lat from the map itself.

I have this for the part where the function is used:

```
   <Map
    initialViewState={{
      center: [0,0],
      zoom: 0.7,
    }}
    style={{width: "100vw", height: "100vh"}}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
    mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN}
    onDblClick = {handleAddClick}
>
```

And this is where my function is written:

```
  const handleAddClick = (e) =>{
    const [longitude, latitude] = e.lngLat;
    setNewIdea({
      lat: latitude,
      long: longitude,
    });
  };
```

This is where I call the function:

```
{newIdea && (
     <Popup 
    longitude={newIdea.long} 
    latitude={newIdea.lat}
    anchor="left"
    closeButton ={true}
    closeOnClick={false}
    onClose={() => setNewIdea(null)}>
      Hey
    </Popup> 
    )}
    </Map>
```

The app runs well but nothing happens when I double click. If I open the console in the browser I get this error every time I double click:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at handleAddClick (App.js:33:1)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your function seems to have different names. You defined them as handleMarkerClick and your function is handleAddClick. Are they two different functions?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I added the wrong part of the code. I edited and added more information to give more clarity too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is coming from this line:

```
const [longitude, latitude] = e.lngLat;
```

Then there is a good chance that e.lngLat is not an array as you’re expecting. Where is that field getting set? It’s likely not getting set in the way you’re expecting.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't an array. Using the e.lngLat.toArray() made it work. Thanks for the observation!

Comment: Glad it worked! Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
const { lat, lng: long } = e.lngLat;

const handleAddClick = (e) => {
  const [lat, long] = e.lngLat;
  setNewPlace({ lat, long });
};
```